# html on my ionic 4 app is displaying before my function is called

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await, ionic4

I think I have a problem around synchronicity. I have a an array of matches(i.e. sports fixtures) that I read from firebase and display on screen. Before I want to display these I want to do some manipulation with the values by calling a function.

This function adds a 'Y' value to closestToToday field on the value that is as the name expects closest to today's date.

I'm confident my function addClosestToTodayFlag works correct based on console logs however my screen is displayed before the function is completed.

How do I explicitly make the displaying of the data on screen wait for my function to complete.

```
export class FixturesPage implements OnInit {

    public matches: Array<any>;
    constructor(private matchService: MatchService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.matchService.getMatches().get().then(matchSnapshot => {
            this.matches = [];
            matchSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
                this.matches.push({
                    id: snap.id,
                    date: snap.data().date,
                    team: snap.data().team,
                    home: snap.data().home,
                    away: snap.data().away,
                    homeScore: snap.data().homeScore,
                    awayScore: snap.data().awayScore,
                    closestToToday: "N",
                });
                return false;
            });                
            this.addClosestToTodayFlag(this.matches);
         });        
    }
```

```
    private async addClosestToTodayFlag(fixtures: Array<any>)
    {   
        var today = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
        var fixtureClosestToToday = Math.abs(today - 
                 fixtures[0].date.seconds);

        fixtures[0].closetToToday = "Y";
        for (var i = 1; i < fixtures.length; i++)
        {
             var currentFixtureTimeToToday = Math.abs(today - 
                 fixtures[i].date.seconds);           
             /* 
              * If the difference in time between today and the 
                current fixture we are looping on is less than the 
              * difference in time of the current shortest gap then we 
                have a new fixture closest to Today
             */
             if (currentFixtureTimeToToday < fixtureClosestToToday)
                {
                    fixtureClosestToToday = currentFixtureTimeToToday;
                    fixtures[i].closetToToday="Y";
                    fixtures[i-1].closetToToday="N";    
                }
            else{
                fixtures[i].closetToToday="N";
              }            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push the matches to the `this.matches` attribute, the view gets updated immediately. So in order to only show the matches when your `addClosestToTodayFlag` function finished you should call it, wait for it and then update the `matches` array.

The way I would do it is to create a variable to store the "raw" matches and then call addClosestToTodayFlag with this, pushing the result to this.matches once it finished.

Insdead of `this.matches = [];` at the beginning of the function, create a temporary variable like `recievedMatches`, push to this variable and pass it to addClosestToTodayFlag.

inside addClosestToTodayFlag, return a promise containing the result data and 
then push the result data to this.matches.

**Update**
Here you have a code-example (not tested but I think this should work). I would say you don't even need to make addClosestToTodayFlag async or return a promise, as it does not seem to perform any asyncronous tasks anyways.

```
export class FixturesPage implements OnInit {
    public matches: Array<any>;
    constructor(private matchService : MatchService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.matchService.getMatches().get().then(matchSnapshot => {
            let matches = [];
            matchSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
                matches.push({
                    id: snap.id,
                    date: snap.data().date,
                    team: snap.data().team,
                    home: snap.data().home,
                    away: snap.data().away,
                    homeScore: snap.data().homeScore,
                    awayScore: snap.data().awayScore,
                    closestToToday: "N"
                });
                return false;
            });
            this.matches = this.addClosestToTodayFlag(matches);
        });
    }

    private addClosestToTodayFlag(fixtures : Array<any>): Array<any> {
        var today = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        var fixtureClosestToToday = Math.abs(today - fixtures[0].date.seconds);

        fixtures[0].closetToToday = "Y";
        for (var i = 1; i < fixtures.length; i++) {
            var currentFixtureTimeToToday = Math.abs(today - fixtures[i].date.seconds);
            /*
             * If the difference in time between today and the
               current fixture we are looping on is less than the
             * difference in time of the current shortest gap then we
               have a new fixture closest to Today
            */
            if (currentFixtureTimeToToday < fixtureClosestToToday) {
                fixtureClosestToToday = currentFixtureTimeToToday;
                fixtures[i].closetToToday = "Y";
                fixtures[i - 1].closetToToday = "N";
            } else {
                fixtures[i].closetToToday = "N";
            }
        }

        return fixtures
    }
}
```

Comment: makes sense but any syntax pointers for the changes in addClosestToTodayFlag()? Apologies I'm relatively new to this stuff!

Comment: @BarrytheBeginner sorry, did not see your answer there. I updated the answer with a little code example, hope it works.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for @carnageous. Thank you for your help.